# Update: PHP how to make a page to display info from sql for one ID?

Tags: php, database, forms

I want to be able to click on the title of my entry like on a blog and have it go to a separate page only displaying info for that specific title.

I have done a lot of searching through this site and can't find anything that goes with what I want.

I have my php set up to connect to my database and everything, I just don't seem to know how to write it so that when I click from the main page it will create another page.

is there a way to create a link so that it searches for title name and finds the post_id or my primary key and have it display everything with that.

My previous question before this was considered a dumb question so i'm revising it. Thanks.

Comment: Are you really saying that you are storing the data in the database and then also creating a cached html version of the page for faster recovery in the future without having to go to the database?

Comment: You should read the guidelines with regards to how to ask questions here, you are unlikely to get much response when you are asking people here to write the code for you. Guidelines - http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: "if possible can you write the code to which file needs to hold it" -no

Comment: well i have code written to make the page display information, i just want specific data to be shown when i click on the title of the entry. so if i rephrase it, is there a way to have a template page get opened then only the data of the title i click on display.

Answer (score 2):

This is a terrible idea. You're basically asking how to create potentially thousands upon thousands of pages that accomplish the same thing.

Write one page that takes the information you want based on some unique ID and displays it in a template so that you have a) minimal code to write b) minimal pages to maintain and c) consistency within your site.

Comment: okay, i'm new to this, i thought this is how it worked when i visit other websites. i guess what i'm trying to do is, when they click on the title, i want it to go to a seaparte page and display only info for that title. how can this be done then?

Comment: @user1557936 learn a scripting language such as Python or PHP. I can't give write a book for you here.  W3Schools has a good tutorial for PHP: http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp ; as far as Python, I'm not familiar with it, so I can't give my opinion on how good a certain tutorial is vs any others.